# Is pocketing an opponent's coin considered a foul?

Tags: carrom

While playing Carrom, if I accidentally pocket (clear from the board) one of my opponent's pieces (coins), is this considered a foul?

Comment: @Malco why did you add "without pocketing one of my own" to the question? I wouldn't have inferred it from OP's original question.

Comment: @BenjaminCosman: Removed now. Shibu: Please roll back my edit if needed for the best description of the question to be answered..

Comment: @BenjaminCosman was trying to make the question a bit clearer. I am fine with the revert if you think I overreached in my edit.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Laws of Carrom](http://www.carrom.co.uk/laws-of-carrom/#XVI) **125**

> When a player pockets the C/M of his opponent knowingly or unknowingly, the Umpire shall stop the player from playing further. If unnoticed by the Umpire or by the opponent, the C/M pocketed shall be considered to have been properly pocketed. The turn of the player shall be lost as and when noticed.

So, while the action is not itself a foul, you do lose the turn, and should the action be noticed immediately the pocketed C/M is returned to the board.

Comment: I have seen official rules that state the c/m is *not* returned but is considered pocketed. ["74) If a player pockets the Striker with the C/m of his opponent by a proper stroke, the C/m so pocketed shall be deemed to have been pocketed. The Due as per Rule 72(a) shall be taken out for placing and the player shall lose his turn."](https://icf-media.beepworld.de/laws-of-carrom.htm)

Answer (score -1):

No, It is not a foul. However after pocketing the opponents coin you lose your turn to play.

Comment: Welcome to the site! When answering a question, it is a best-practice to cite (and link to) a specific source for your answer. These sources provide an authoritative reference and make it easier for the OP to select the Right answer based on objective standards, instead of what could be just a subjective opinion. I would suggest updating your answer with a link to the rules where you found this information.